# Spivak's Calculus Chapter 3 Problem 25

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification, functional-equations, fake-proofs

Find a function f(x) such that g(f(x)) = x for some g(x), but such that there is no function h(x) with f(h(x)) = x.

I think I've got something backwards in my head because I can easily find the reverse case and this case seems provably impossible.

I start with Spivak's definition of a function as a set of ordered pairs:

Suppose f(x) = { (1,2) , (3,4) }

I.e: f(1) = 2 and f(3) = 4 and undefined for everything else.

Clearly you can find h(x) such that f(h(x)) = x, just take the set of the pairs switched around.

h(x) = { (2,1) , (4,3) }

I.e: h(2) = 1 and h(4) = 3 and undefined for everything else.

The only way I can see to get around this problem is to choose order pairs that have the same last term:

Suppose f(x) = { (1,3) , (2,3) }

I.e: f(1) = 3 and f(2) = 3 and undefined for everything else.

Now you can't find just flip the pairs because then h(x) wouldn't be a function:

If h(x) = { (3,1) , (3,2) } Then does h(3) = 1 or 2? It's ambiguous!

But you can still find h(x), just pick one of the pairs and exclude the other(s).

h(x) = { (3,1) }

f(h(x)) = x still holds?

Furthermore, the same logic can seemingly be applied to g(x) to prove g(x) doesn't exist!

Suppose f(x) = { (1,3) , (2,3) }

We need to find g(x) such that g(f(x)) = x

So g(f(1)) = 1 and g(f(2)) = 2

But f(1) = f(2) = 3 !!!

So 1 = g(f(1)) = g(3) = g(f(2)) = 2

1 = 2 !!!

What have I done?

Comment: You need to define a domain and range for your functions.

Comment: Not if I'm using the definition of a function? But either way: Domain is the set of all the first values of order pairs and Range is the set of all the second values of ordered pairs.

Comment: Ah you mean in the original problem, domain and range need to be defined! Yes now I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Please learn how to use mathjax to typeset your questions!

Comment: ... Yeah nah...

Comment: @Paul Frost I wrote that question haha. Yes I have an answer to the my above problem, basically that Spivak didn't define his concept properly. But that led me to ask why didn't he define his concept properly which has led to new possible answers to my above problem (still on going). It's a different question hence why I made a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ given by $x \mapsto x^2$

$g:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ given by $x \mapsto \lfloor \sqrt{x}\rfloor$ is such that $g(f(x)) = x \; \forall x \in \mathbb{N}$.

But there is no function $h: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(h(x)) = x$ since that would imply that every natural number is a square.

Comment: But who said h had to be N -> N ? Let h(x) = { (1,1) (4,2) (9,3) ... } Now f(h(x)) = x no ?

Comment: If you say f(h(x)) = x has to be true for all x in N, then where did that fact come from? And why N? For example g(f(x)) = x is not true if x is in R. But x in N seems as arbitrary as x in R?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start thinking of the domain and co-domain for your functions. Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a function. We want $g(f(x)) = x$. So given an element in $B$, where should $g$ map it to? As you suggested, we can "flip it around". A requisite condition for this to work is that $f$ must be injective (one-to-one), otherwise there might be ambiguity in what element you want $g$ to map to.

So how do we ensure that there is no function such that $f(h(x)) = x$? Well, what if you have an element in $B$ that has no element in $A$ mapping to it under $f$? No matter where $h$ takes this element, it cannot be "mapped back" to itself.

Comment: "Given an element in B". Why must it be an element in B? What if x is chosen such that f(x) is undefined, the same way we are forcing h(x) to be undefined?

Comment: I am not too sure whether I understand your question. We are not forcing h(x) to be undefined. Rather we're showing that there is no way to construct h such that f(h(x)) = x if f is not surjective. g is a function with domain B hence your quoted sentence. f(x) is always defined (by definition of function it has to map x to something in B). When we chose x in the case of h, we chose it in the codomain of f so f did not have to map to it. In the 1st case, x is in the domain of f and thus must map to something in B.

Comment: I haven't learnt what those words mean yet so I find your answer incomprehensible. But I think I did find the error in my thinking. See my answer at the bottom or if TLDR: I thought g(f(x)) = x meant for all x in the domain of f. Turns out that's not true. g(f(x)) = x means for all x in the range of g.

Comment: I have done further investigation and discovered I am wrong again. Pls help.

Comment: Ok so I took the time to learn your terms. My problem is with the last sentence:  "Well, what if you have an element in B that has no element in A mapping to it under f? No matter where h takes this element, it cannot be "mapped back" to itself." Easy, just don't have h(x) be defined at that element.

Comment: Give me an example of such functions and I'll show you.

Comment: First of all for f(h(x)) = x to be defined, the domain of h must equal the codomain of f since the function x is really the identity defined on B (if you look at the original problem carefully, it uses I, the identity, instead of x). So if you don't define h(x) for a certain element of B, h is no longer a well defined function. In other words every element inB must be mapped to something in A under h. Things would be different however if you wanted a function h s.t. f(h(x)) is the inclusion map.

Comment: We're getting closer but I still don't understand. What difference does it make if the problem uses the identity function instead of x? And much more importantly, I think this might be the crux: why is the identity necessarily defined on B? When I read f(h(x)) = I(x) = x, to me that means for x in the domain of h, not the codomain of f? But even if it does, if there exists an element in B that doesn't get "mapped to from A" by f, then B isn't the codomain of f, it's a superset of the codomain of f??

Comment: I have learnt something. Codomain is not the same thing as the Image. The image of a function is the set of all the second values of the ordered pairs. This is what I was thinking of. But the codomain is any superset of the image? That's arbitrary, then every function has an infinite number of codomains? And what's the point? If f(x) and g(x) are the same set of ordered pairs, but I pick different codomains for each, are they now different functions? Even though f(x) = g(x) for all x when both sides are defined?

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Two functions can only be equal if they have the same codomain. The problem was Spivak never defined functions to include a codomain, only their domain and set of ordered pairs. In this theory, every function is surjective! Which means the question he asked is completely impossible. Why did he ask it then? I will be creating a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Find a function f(x) such that g(f(x)) = x for some g(x), but such that there is no function h(x) with f(h(x)) = x.

Technically this is impossible. The question should be:

Find a function f(x): A -> B, such that g(f(x)) = x for some g(x) for all x in A, but such that there is no function h(x) with f(h(x)) = x for all x in B.

Now I get it.

Edit: I am wrong. I do not understand.

Comment: It comes down to an ambiguity of what g(f(x)) = x means exactly (or equivalently what f(h(x)) = x means). There are 4 possible interpretations at play here. 1) g(f(x)) = x is for any x. Literally anything, including non-numbers. This definition is absurd and you can't find either h(x) or g(x), so we'll move on.

Comment: Interpretation 2) g(f(x)) = x means if I choose a specific number/object x, such that f(x) is defined and g(f(x)) is defined, then when I compute g(f(x)) I get back x. Using this interpretation the question is impossible, because h(x) always exists.

Comment: Interpretation 3) g(f(x)) = x means if I choose x such that f(x) is defined but not necessarily g(f(x)), then when I compute g(f(x)) I get back x. This to me is what I understood g(f(x)) = x to mean. But again it doesn't work because h(x) always exists.

Comment: Interpretation 4) g(f(x)) = x means if you choose any number/object x that the function g can possibly spit out, then g(f(x)) = x. I find it strange that this turns out to be the correct interpretation. Seems remarkably unclear. But it works because you have to be able to find g(f(x)) given x in g's domain. The others did the opposite, find x given x in f's domain.

Comment: Update: I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got down to the root of the issue.

*Q25) Find a function f(x) such that g(f(x)) = x for some g(x), but such that there is no function h(x) with f(h(x)) = x.*

This question is completely impossible. In fact, questions 22 - 28 are all poorly defined. Why? Because Spivak has not defined what it means for 2 functions to be equal to each other. But it gets worse, his theory actually informally infers a different definition of equality for which it is impossible find f(x) and g(x)!

This is Spivak's definition of a function (Page 47):

*A function is a collection of pairs of numbers with the following property: if (a,b) and (a,c) are both in the collection, then b = c; in other words, the collection must not contain two different pairs with the same first element.*

(I am using Spivak's Calculus 4th edition btw)

No definition for equality of functions is given, but given Spivak's definition of a function as a set of ordered pairs, the reasonable expectation would be 2 functions are equal when their set of ordered pairs are equal.

However this approach to defining functions is NOT the modern standard. There is a very subtle difference, but it is what makes Q25 possible: the concept of codomain. A function is NOT only a set of ordered pairs, it is 2 sets: One of them is it's normal set of ordered pairs (x,y), and the other its codomain set which has the property that it contains all possible values of y. The critical point is the codomain set need not contain ONLY all possible values of y, it can have other elements too.

Why does this change anything? Because now when you define equality of functions, not only must the set of ordered pairs of the 2 functions be equal, the 2 functions must have the same CODOMAIN.

This changes things because only with the concept of codomain can you have non-surjective functions. Using Spivak's incorrect definition, there are no non-sujective functions, in fact the concept of non-surjectivity doesn't exist at all! And the trick to Q25 is you have to choose f(x) to be a non-surjective function.

Now my question is why on earth has Spivak put this problem in this exercise if he not only doesn't provide the definitions required to solve the problem, he puts in INCORRECT definitions that make the problem impossible? But that's a different question...

Comment: Spivak's definition is not incorrect, it is a very special case of the general set-theoretic approach. He defines a function as a suitable subset $f$ of $\mathbb R \times\mathbb R$ . He defines the concept of *domain* of $f$ (a subset of $\mathbb R$), but he does not use the concept of *codomain*. In his approach this is in fact irrelevant - he simply does not need it. If you want, you can imagine that all functions have codomain $\mathbb R$. See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3790342. However, it is of course worthy of discussion whether Spivak's approach is *modern*.

Comment: Yes, that's right, that is the problem. Without the concept of codomain, it is not possible to answer problem 25 in the chapter's problem set. Because problem 25 requires you to find an injective non-surjective function. But non-surjective functions don't exist without the concept of codomain. Someone did mention an alternative explanation if we assume all the functions must have the same domain, but that assumption appears arbitrary to me.

Comment: A function is surjective iff its image is $\mathbb R$. You can use this as the *definition of surjective* even you do not use the concept of codomain: The image of a  function $f \subset \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ is the set of all $y \in \mathbb R$ for which you find  $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $(x,y) \in f$