# Ambiguous notation in Spivak's Calculus: $f \circ g = I$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

There are a few concepts I have come across that are causing me a little confusion. This question is motivated by the repeated usage of the notation $f \circ g = I$ in Michael Spivak's *Calculus*

---

Firstly, consider the **function composition** $f \circ g$. Let $f: A \to B$ and $g: C \to D$.

When understanding the notion of a composition's domain $\text{dom}(f \circ g)$, we need to consider the fact that $g$'s range $g[C]$ may not necessarily fully intersect with the $\text{dom}(f)=A$. Therefore, a given $x \in \text{dom}(g)= C$ is only in $\text{dom}(f \circ g)$ if $g(x) \in A$. From this, it is apparent that $\text{dom}(f \circ g) \subseteqq C$. Call this $C^*$.

(The above description is consistent with Spivak's definition of a composition's domain)

Now that we have characterized the notion of a composition's domain as $C^*$, it is straightforward to understand what we mean by the range of the composition $\text{ran}(f \circ g)$...specifically, $\text{ran}(f \circ g)=\text{ran}(f \upharpoonright C^*)$.

---

Secondly, consider a **relation inverse** $R^{-1}$, which we define as $R^{-1}=\{\langle y,x \rangle | \langle x, y \rangle \in R\}$. For a function $f$, $f^{-1}$ will only be a function if $f$ is injective (also referred to as '$\text{1-1}$').

---

I want to take a look at what one means implicitly when the following is written: $f \circ g = I$, where $I$ is the identity function. Given our earlier comments on compositions, $I$ is *forced* to be defined as follows: $I = \{\langle x,x \rangle \  |\  x \in C^*\}$.

Let $f$ be **neither** injective nor surjective. Let there be no restrictions on how we construct $g$. Prove that there exists a $g$ such that $f \circ g = I$.

Because $f$ is not injective, there exists an $x_1 \neq x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Let's create a $g$ that purposefully avoids mapping into such elements (we will denote these as "**bad elements"** of $f$). So as to avoid invoking the Axiom of Choice, we will specify that for all elements in $\text{dom}(f)$ that are mapped to a common element in $\text{ran}(f)$ (the so-called *bad elements*), $g$ will not take any of its elements from $\text{dom}(g)$ into those bad elements of $\text{dom}(f)$. As a second property, let $\text{dom}(g) \subseteqq \text{ran}(f)$. For the final property, let us impose that $g$ is injective; this condition may require the $\text{dom}(g)$ to be trimmed so that the adherence to the first condition doesn't make the $|\text{ran}(g)|$ *too small*.

Define $g$ to have the following mapping rule: $x \mapsto f^{-1}(x)$ where $f(y)=x$. Importantly, because $g$ avoids mapping into any of the *bad elements* of $f$, the notion of $f^{-1}$ is unambiguous. That is to say, $f\upharpoonright \text{dom}(g)$ is injective...*by design*.

It would seem that I have successfully created a $g$ that satisfies the statement: $f \circ g = I$

---

To me, the statement $f \circ g = I$ is incredibly ambiguous. There is a problem in Spivak's book that amounts to saying: Prove that $f$ must be surjective in order for there to exist a function $g$ such that $f \circ g = I$. Well, I just did this...but as far as I can tell, it did not require $f$ to be surjective.

The issue seems to be in how one defines the domain of the Identity Function $I$. With a notation like $f \circ g = I$, it appears there are degrees of freedom in my choice of $g$ that should not be there.

Comment: This is a comment more than an answer. A way out of ambiguity is to agree that a function consists of three components: its domain, its codomain, and the functional assignment. We then write $f\colon A\to B$. This is not ambiguous. Further, we agree that the composition $f\circ g$ exists only if $g\colon A\to B$ and $f\colon B\to C$. Further still, by identity function we always mean a function $h\colon A\to A$ with $h(a)=a$. No ambiguity. In calculus it is customary to speak of, e.g., $f(x)=\sqrt x$ and allow the rule to dictate the domain. This introduces ambiguity. So, let's not do that.

Comment: @IttayWeiss thank you for the input. Your definitions certainly eliminate the ambiguity. Unfortunately, Spivak's definitions do not. For example, he writes: "...the domain of $f \circ g$ is $\{x : x \text{ is in domain } g \text{ and } g(x) \text{ is in domain } f \}$."

Comment: Spivak defines a function as a set of ordered pairs of real numbers. According to this definition, the following two functions are *identical*: the function $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^2$; the function $g:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ given by $g(x)=x^2$. Under this definition, it does make much sense to speak of a function being injective, surjective, or bijective. We can only meaningfully speak of functions being many-to-one or one-to-one.

Comment: @S.Cramer I know. That is why I labeled my comment as a non-answer. Instead of resolving the problem I suggest adopting a formalism that does not introduce the problem in the first place.

Comment: There is certainly an issue with "the" identity function: no such function exists. Instead, the standard method is to define an identity function *on each set $X$*: $\text{Id}_X = \{(x,x) \mid x \in X\}$.

Comment: So the meaning of the statement $f \circ g = I$ itself is ambiguous: $f$ and $g$ are given, but "the" identity function $I$ has not been given. I suppose that you could treat $X$ as an unknown set and ask for solutions to the equation $f \circ g = \text{Id}_X$.

Comment: As for the question of Spivak in the final paragraph of your post, I would have to see the complete statement of the question to be able to comment definitively. As copied in your post, that question is missing specifications on the domains and ranges of the functions $f$ and $g$ and on the identity function $I$. The most straightforward theorem that I can think of along those lines would be that for any function $f$, the existence of a function $g$ such that $f \circ g = \text{Id}_{\text{dom}(g)}$ is equivalent to the statement $\text{dom}(g) \subset \text{ran}(f)$.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the problem? (Chapter 3, Problem 23, 3rd Ed.):

> 23. Suppose that $f\circ g = I$, where $I(x) = x$. Prove that
>
> (a) if $x\neq y$, then $g(x) \neq g(y)$;
>
> (b) every number $b$ can be written $b = f(a)$ for some number $a$.

I probably don't know enough about modern function theory to address much of this but there was a related discussion you might find useful [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790342/misleading-definitions-and-unanswerable-problems-in-spivaks-calculus/3790468#3790468)

If I have the correct problem, Spivak in this case seems to want us to assume that here, for every real number $x$, $f(g(x)) = x$. Were this not the case, (b) would not necessarily be true. By asking us to prove something is true he implies enough information to make it true, but it wouldn't be true without those assumptions.

The takeaway from this problem, that $f\circ g = I$ $\implies$

(a) $g$ must be one-one, and

(b) every real number $x = f(a)$ for some real number $a$

are perhaps not interesting to folks with previous experience dealing with function and set theory :)

Comment: Thank you for the link! Very hepful.